# How to manage files in /var/log/journal/ in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: logging, ubuntu-18.04, diskspace, journal

I want to learn about and manage the directory */var/log/journal/* in ubuntu 18.04

- What data is logged to it and when?
- Is there any issue in deleting all files from that directory?
- Is there any way to set delete old data (eg. 1 month)?

Comment: `Refer this link to solve the issue` - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238214/big-var-log-journal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have learned it in weak end - adding a short note here

- journald is - systemd’s logging service
- Journalctl is a utility for querying and displaying logs from journald
- the logs are stored in /var/log/journal/ (except, when we delete the directory)
- we can manage the size and etc in /etc/systemd/journald.conf
- useful journalctl commands

  - journalctl  - to view all logs
  - journalctl --disk-usage - to check disk usage
  - journalctl --since "2020-09-24 00:00:00" --until "2020-09-24 23:59:59" - to view logs in between this time range
  - journalctl -f - tail the logs

Comment: link to the [manpage of journald.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/journald.conf.5.html)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130786/can-i-remove-files-in-var-log-journal-and-var-cache-abrt-di-usr/130802#130802